# How to declare types for an array of objects whose properties are interdependent?

Tags: typescript, generics

I would like to declare type for object (`root`), that contains nested array of objects (`values`), where each object has properties `one` (any type) and `all` (array of `one`'s type).

Bellow is my attempt to do it, however I don't know how to obtain types of `one`property, so there is just `Value<any>`:

```js
type Value<T> = { one: T, all: T[] }
type Root = { values: Value<any>[] }

const root: Root = {
    values: [
        { one: 1, all: 5 }, // Should be error, 'all' should be an array of numbers.
        { one: true, all: [5] }, // Should be error, 'all' should be array of booleans.
        { one: 'a', all: ['a', 'b', 'c'] }, // Ok.
        { one: true, all: [false, true, true] } // Ok.
    ]
}
```

Is there any way how to do that? Here is [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK4QDwBUB8UC8UDeUA9gHYQBcU6ANFIgpegNoC6UAvgFCiRQBKRIsFwEoAN0QoAzpXjI0cEiEysOnTgGNSU4QCdBwSgKEj8nKBfGSIMqE3OXHhUhSgBGWvUoBWDrQD0-lAAorr6urQA5PSRUFIAFkRICAAmUABG0Ip0YXAgxABmUCRIALaZulIAdA6OFs5klMC6KJ4IDHbebOwBQaHhUTFxiclpmTm6eYUZgggQitW1dQ2u0ZFtHUxrUenrUJEakd29UADyANY1dZYrTS0QG5RMBYhSD1DNrR-33VCBZ5clixOOwgA). It would be amazing, if it could be without naming all possible combinations of types like:

```
type Value = { one: string, all: string[] } | { one: number, all: number[] } | { one: boolean, all: boolean[] }
```

because it should be applicable to any type.

Comment: I don't think you can do this without naming all combinaisons. `<T>` is global to your array, so basically all T types can be anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you note, your `Root` value is too wide to enforce the constraint you care about, but it does have the advantage of being straightforward to use:

```
const root: Root = {
    values: [
        { one: true, all: [5] }, // uh oh no error
        { one: 'a', all: ['a', 'b', 'c'] }, // okay
        { one: true, all: [false, true, true] } // okay
    ]
}

const indexes = root.values.map(v => v.all.indexOf(v.one));
console.log(indexes) // [-1, 0, 1]
```

I'm showing the above for comparison purposes.  The following approach will enforce the constraint, but you will end up paying for that with some loss of convenience.

---

When you find yourself wishing you could write an infinite [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) like the invalid

```
type SomeValue = Value<string> | Value<number> | Value<boolean> 
  | Value<null> | Value<Date> | Value<{a: string, b: number}> | ...
```

it's a sign that you are looking for *existentially* quantified generic types.  Most languages with generics, including TypeScript, only directly support *universally* quantified generic types (which correspond to infinite [intersection types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types)).  There is a feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#14466](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466) to support existentially quantified generics, but it's not part of the language yet.

Still, it is possible to emulate these generics.  The difference between existential and universal generics has to do with who gets to specify the type parameter.  If you switch the role of data supplier and data consumer, then universals become existentials.  So we can encode `SomeValue` like this:

```
type SomeValue = <R>(cb: <T>(value: Value<T>) => R) => R;
```

Let's say you have a value `someValue` of type `SomeValue`.  If you want to access the underlying `Value<T>` data, you need to call `someValue()` with some callback `cb` that *receives* the `Value<T>` and does something with it.  It's like an immediately resolved `Promise`.  The `cb` callback must be prepared for any possible `Value<T>` value; whoever supplies `value` gets to choose what `T` is. All you can say is that it's *some* `T`.

You can write a helper function to turn any `Value<T>` into a `SomeValue`:

```
const toSomeValue = <T,>(value: Value<T>): SomeValue => cb => cb(value);
```

And then your `Root` would be

```
type Root = { values: SomeValue[] }
```

Which means you can now create `root` as follows:

```
const root: Root = {
    values: [
        toSomeValue({ one: true, all: [5] }), // error!
        toSomeValue({ one: 'a', all: ['a', 'b', 'c'] }), // okay
        toSomeValue({ one: true, all: [false, true, true] }) // okay
    ]
}
```

Here you've got the type checking you wanted (with the penalty that you needed to write `toSomeValue()` a bunch of times).  And now you can make `indexes` from before by pushing your old `v => v.all.indexOf(v.one)` callback down into `someV`:

```
const indexes = root.values.map(someV => someV(v => v.all.indexOf(v.one)));
console.log(indexes) // [-1, 0, 1]
```

So it produces the same result, but again, with more complexity.

---

Now you *might* want to try to make `Root` generic itself, where you [map an array type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) to an array of `Value<T>` for individual `T` types.  And then you could either manually annotate that `root` is, say, `Root<[5, "a" | "b" | "c", boolean]>`, or try to get the compiler to *infer* `[5, "a" | "b" | "c", boolean]` from the initializer to the `values` property.  These approaches are technically possible, but they add even more complexity than the existential type encoding above, and they are not as type safe.  So I won't go into detail here; although the code is included in the link at the bottom of the answer.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-zlSKlqm1mjcittQSj9o1KK9SBe7gzXm4Pkq2cSEzCPtzct+U1qMQ2CWCKSUcMGxVKvDQAEIa346-row2m8J2vNElOuj0+qku8S9mMh9LfaP7Y2ldFZtPgstaKtxC21qfF8uRqvDsdfJriKjdPjHlBnm53nKoF8fr80QbY3+0b-LGwKgs+UIwvCCIeg+Tjopi2K4s+hLLmSlJIDSSB0pKDKMuA0BwIgSAAOLCiUGDwJ4ugEKEMpIAAcrwACSwCLCU1p6DILByFxxT3LytyvpYZBIAA-BhSDCAI+glHIyK0em9oceWO4McxrHsew+5oBAIA3PwtAibIqQKeoVGsHxAk3K+Ol6QZInCfIHAqVWPAyAA0lcwBIMMEBkLwiwiHIobmKwHlyBwih2AWFwuG4HhuEwyTiAARCAKVIAAPkgKWdBl2UpfAKXiJ02gYpYEXeEOrkhIc4Sqae+7JAMy4lGUg51cQE71I0TWznU3TiL0-RKN2V4HJ1PA1LurZqgeKxnnumzbLs41DrexD3g4hYgFAVGBpZwrWUWun6cAhkSFYTm-MWCU6OGsbFvJnqxaqaL7dwu1UY21WfokrW9gOa5dQ1S1ts1o3A1UqmzuD-WDfUC6Q5NU3TI1qoLIex6bCeswmTeEivo+Jxwqm22vYsGCPDcehfW4P2HDVUOo7USRNR2aTM91sNzTI8PziNnMo916Pg1ji0bOedgE7tcZeiTiKXvsoTpAAVHLFNUxANzCBWRCubZZ0XTISlJGw4hKWl+U5XlWU5UV5tIEppXwZYbByScSCq+kZMa5cyGvtwxYfoE35-P8IWMEwwmOiBIItGCtwPBBwJQYruyFN66ZQCAbExWiGJYjieJJy+RK7Gh1K0sc+CKEAA)

Answer (score 0):

In Your case `T` is any because it can be a string, number or boolean. So I would not recommend it.
You can just use something like that:

```
type Value = number | string | boolean
type ValueObject = { one: Value; all: Value[] }
type Root = { values: ValueObject[] }
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no; I don't believe there's a way to do what you're trying to do. The longer answer is you probably shouldn't do it.

You could probably store the type information like this:

```
const root: Root = {
    values: [
        { one: 1, all: 5 } as Value<number>, // Should be error, 'all' should be an array of numbers.
        { one: true, all: [5] } as Value<boolean>, // Should be error, 'all' should be array of booleans.
        { one: 'a', all: ['a', 'b', 'c'] } as Value<string>, // Ok.
        { one: true, all: [false, true, true] } as Value<boolean> // Ok.
    ]
}
```

...but, I'm struggling to think of a downstream consumption where you'll loop over `root.values` and not need conditionals for processing the struct like this:

```
const process = (root) => {
  switch(typeof root) {
    case "number":
      ...
      break
    case "string":
      ...
      break
    case "boolean":
      ...
      break
  }

}
```

Instead, you could simplify the whole flow by replacing the `root` with something like:

```
const intRoots: Value<number>[]
const boolRoots: Value<boolean>[]
const strRoots: Value<string>[]
```

then process each type explicitly without type checking:
`const ***Roots.map(...)`

A rationalization I fallback on quite frequently (though there are certainly exceptions) is if I'm struggling to manage types in my processing then it's worth revisiting the data structure