# Partial type constraint on generic array of objects

Tags: typescript, generics

I have the following javascript that I would like to add type annotations to:

```
// Run state through a transform and call a side effect.
function transformWithSideEffect(state, transformers) {
  transformers.forEach(
    transformer => transformer.effect(
      transformer.transform(state)
    )
  );
}

const state = {
  a: 123,
  b: [ "abc", "xyz" ],
};

let transforms = [];

transforms.push({ transform: (state) => state.a, effect: (state) => { console.log(state); } });

for (let i = 0; i < state.b.length; i++) {
    transforms.push({ transform: (state) => state.b[i], effect: (state) => { console.log(state); } });
}

transformWithSideEffect(state, transforms);
```

How would I add a constraint on the type within the array (in this case, the return value of the transform function and the input parameter of the effect function, without forcing all elements of the array to be of the same type?

i.e. Something like the following works, but only if all transformers have the same type for S and T, which is not what I want.

```
interface Transformer<S, T> {
    transform: (state: S) => T;
    effect: (state: T) => void;
}

// Run state through a transform and call a side effect.
function transformWithSideEffect<S, T>(state: S, transformers: Transformer<S, T>[]) {
  transformers.forEach(
    transformer => transformer.effect(
      transformer.transform(state)
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: They all have the same `S`, right?  It's just the `T` that could be different.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: If I'm right then the typing for `transformWithSideEffect` should be written in terms of a *tuple* type for `T`, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w2aR1W).  It's a bit unfortunate (and possibly out of scope for the question) that the compiler can't infer the type of the `effect` callback parameter; I'd have thought [this feature](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-7/#improved-function-inference-in-objects-and-methods) might have enabled it, but it doesn't look as though that is happening.  So you have to write `(state: number) => ...` instead of just `state => ...`

Comment: Does that fully address your question? If so I can write up an answer explaining how it works.  If not, what am I missing, and can you [edit] the question to demonstrate failed use cases?

Comment: Looks promising, but sadly I don't think I can get away with a statically typed tuple, as I will be building up the input array dynamically. I think fundamentally what I'm after is a type containing two any attributes, but with a constraint that both of the any's are the same type.

Comment: Please could you [edit] to show what you mean by “building up the input array dynamically”?  If your example code doesn’t demonstrate a required use case then it’s very difficult for others to satisfy it.

Comment: I've updated the example to show my use-case for a dynamic array of transforms. Could probably get away with a tuple type if I introduced another 'flatten' transform input that took care of applying the transform to each item of the nested array.

Comment: Ah, yes, for this you really want *existentially quantified generic types*, which TypeScript doesn't directly support, although they can be emulated. I've written answers about this sort of thing before, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69338092/2887218) for example.  The translation of that approach here looks like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mMMY1m).  I'm inclined to close this as a duplicate of the other question, or else my answer would look nearly identical to that one.  Thoughts?

Comment: Great thanks - I agree this is essentially a duplicate of that question and can be closed. As for whether the work-around leaves me with a path forward, I'm not so sure! Seems the cognitive burden to understand the workaround may be more than the benefit gained by the strong typing...